# Java JWebbrowser DocumentCompleted Event

Tags: java, cross-platform, browser, swt

I am working on chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser, I tried demo and everything looks fine but I was unable to find any event to detect documentcomplete

Comment: It would be nice if you can share the link of the JWebBrowser.

Comment: link to project http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html a java demo app is there to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There were no answers to original question for long time, so i am reporting my findings on the problem, if someone else may like to use.

As far I found there is no DocumentCompleted Event But I have achieved similar results by adding listeners using

```
webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(new WebBrowserListener() {
            public void loadingProgressChanged(WebBrowserEvent wbe) {
                JWebBrowser wb = wbe.getWebBrowser();
                String pageUrl = wb.getResourceLocation();
                int progress = wb.getLoadingProgress();
                if (progress == 100) {
                    String jsCommand = "";
                    ....
                    wb.executeJavascript(jsCommand);

                }
            }
        }
...
```