# document completed event from JWebbrowser

Tags: java, swt

DJNativeSwing JWebBrowser don't have DocumentComplete event, like webbrowser control in C#,

is there any way to duplicate this event behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible alternate

[Java JWebbrowser DocumentCompleted Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908832/java-jwebbrowser-documentcompleted-event)